# Android SQLite Optimization adding rows

Tags: android, sqlite

I am adding about 3000 rows to SQLite database and it takes about 8 seconds. How can I optimize this.

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't already, wrap the entire operation in a transaction. Your code should look something like this:

```java
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    // insert your data here
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Good tip.  I added a transaction around one of my slow save methods and it improved it by a factor of 10.  The "PRAGMA synchronous = OFF" only increased it by a factor of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Try executing `PRAGMA synchronous = OFF` before doing the updates.

Comment: I also saw someone mentioned that compiling SQLite  recompiled sqlite with the SQLITE_NO_SYNC definement and had a huge 
increase in speed.  Any comments.  http://osdir.com/ml/sqlite-users/2010-08/msg00630.html

Comment: Recompiling SQLite isn't going to change the software running on a phone, so I wouldn't go that route. I believe that once you have the SQLiteDatabase object, just calling the `execSQL` method with that statement as the argument before doing the inserts. I haven't tried it, but according to [this](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous), it should make a significant difference.

Comment: @TedHopp Actually, you can run your own version of SQlite.  I think that is what barcodereader was referring to.  I run an encrypted version of Sqlite on Android and iOS for clients with sensitive data (it is a 3rd party implementation that is available to anyone).

Comment: @Henry - That's interesting. Could you make use of any of the built-in data base support provided in the Android APIs, or did you have to completely bypass that. Also, can you share whose encrypted implementation you are using?

Comment: @TedHopp I am using sqlcipher, available at sqlcipher.net.  There is a commercial version and a free Community Edition under a BSD-style open source license.